Simplifying a very large multi-variable expression
I have integrated a function over one variable out of 7 variables as
DistributeDefinitions[AFBC9U];
startTime = LocalTime[]
step = 0.001;
range = Range[0.045, 6, step];
LISTAFBC1s = ParallelTable[AFBC9U*step /. s -> xx, {xx, range}];
Save["E:\\new paper\\My codes\\data\\LISTAFBC1short.mx", LISTAFBC1];
endTime = LocalTime[]
(*and then *)
AFBUsum = Sum[LISTAFBC1[[k]], {k, 1, Dimensions[LISTAFBC1][[1]]}];

This off course gives me a very large expression, which is not simplifiable in anyway because imaginary numbers and variables are everywhere in the numerators and denominators in all terms.
I tried to get an apporximation by this method.
results = {};

For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,
 C7NP = RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
 C7priNP = RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
 C9NP = RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
 C9priNP = RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
 C10NP = RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
 C10priNP = RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
 AFBUsumExpr = C7NP + C7priNP + C9NP + C9priNP + C10NP + C10priNP;
 value = Re[
   AFBUsum /. {C7NP -> C7NP, C7priNP -> C7priNP, C9NP -> C9NP, 
     C9priNP -> C9priNP, C10NP -> C10NP, C10priNP -> C10priNP}];
 AppendTo[
  results, {C7NP, C7priNP, C9NP, C9priNP, C10NP, C10priNP, value}];]

Save["E:\\new paper\\My codes\\data\\dataLISTAFBC1short.mx", results];
results

formula = 
 FindFormula[results, {C7NP, C7priNP, C9NP, C9priNP, C10NP, C10priNP}]

But I am nowhere near to success. How can i get an approximate formula in terms of the variables? Any help will be appreciated.
